# The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

Here is my situation. I have a Windows server box and a Linux box. On my Windows server I have Sharepoint installed and was able to access the shared directory through the Windows command line by executing a `dir` command and also able to map the shared directory to a network drive, both locally.

`dir "\\XX.XX.XX.XX\DavWWWRoot\Shared Documents\AllDocuments\ImpDocuments"`

The issue comes when i try to access the same from a Linux box over ssh.

`ssh -v user@XX.XX.XX.XX cmd /c dir "\\\\XX.XX.XX.XX\\DavWWWRoot\\Shared Documents\\AllDocuments\\ImpDocuments"`

Error: `Access Denied.`

Ideas please!

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config`
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to XX.XX.XX.XX [XX.XX.XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version VShell_4_0_1_478 VShell
debug1: no match: VShell_4_0_1_478 VShell
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'XX.XX.XX.XX' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@XX.XX.XX.XX's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: cmd /c dir \\\\XX>XX.XX.XX\\DavWWWRoot\\Shared Documents\\AllDocuments\\ImpDocuments
Access is denied.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 1824, received 1920 bytes, in 17.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 104.8, received 110.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the backslashes as they are interpreted by the shell:

```
ssh user@XX.XX.XX.XX cmd /c dir "\\\\XX.XX.XX.XX\\DavWWWRoot\\Shared Documents\\AllDocuments\\ImpDocuments"
```

Comment: @techie007, jilliagre - thanks for your response. I have tried what you suggested. I now get the Access Denied error. Can you please check the updated question. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mount the target filesystem on the Linux system prior to accessing it.

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user1,password=abc123 //XX.XX.XX.XX/share /mnt/share
```

Then you can use ls or other utilities to view and/or edit files.

```
ls /mnt/share/file
```

Assuming that works, you can add the mount to the Linux system's /etc/fstab file to mount automatically at boot.

Comment: @baumgart- thanks for your response. But i cannot go for the mounting of drives as it is not permitted. Can you tell me, is there any restriction to access the shared folder of the share point from a Linux box using dir command over SSH ?

Comment: Linux doesn't work like Windows.  In order to see files on another server, you have to mount it (or run a binary that shows them without mounting, such as smbclient).  Bottom line is that it just doesn't work the same.

Comment: thanks again. I too arrived at the similar conclusion from the proceedings. BTW it wold be of helpful if you can provide any reference for this.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a typo in the command that you ran?

```
debug1: Sending command: cmd /c dir \\\\XX>XX.XX.XX\\DavWWWRoot\\Shared...
                                          ^
```

If that's not it, I'd try quoting the windows command so that ssh sees it as a single string. You might have to fiddle with doubling or not doubling the backslashes:

```
ssh -v user@XX.XX.XX.XX 'cmd /c dir "\\\\XX.XX.XX.XX\\[etc]\\ImpDocuments"'
```

If this still doesn't work, try making an interactive SSH connection to the windows server, then try running the `dir` command in that session. It's possible that the Windows SSH server isn't setting up your session correctly, and you don't have access to the network when you come in that way.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I figured out another to get it worked.